# How can I get the accessible location of external storage programmatically in Android 4.4?

Tags: android

In Android 4.4,third party application cant able to access external storage completely.But app can access some location of external storage.How can I get that location programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Set permissions in manifest file

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

then use

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
```